# What does the highlighted part of the following text mean?

Tags: word-meaning

> I may be able to find you guys a place. However, for 3 people would have to be a 2 bedroom. Do you have **a good # to reach you by any chance?**

This is part of an email I recieved today. When saying good# I do not get what it means. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: # means number.

Answer (score 1):

He probably meant "good ***phone*** number", so that it's easier for him to contact you.

The "#" sign can be used as shorthand for the word "number".